# Frequency of multiple boolean or non-boolean columns in R

Tags: r, statistics, frequency

I am a novice to **R**. I have a data frame (imported with read.csv) with >200 columns and >100 rows which are the result of a survey. So, a column or a groups of columns represent the answers to questions. I have two questions.

a) columns with names "Q1", "Q2", ... "Q9" contain booleans (yes/no). What is the command for creating a frequency table which looks like this (i.e.: frequency of true/false for each column over all rows).

```
        q1     q2    q3    ...
true    5      99     11
false   95      1     89
```

b) columns with names "P1", "P2", ... "P9" contain values from a scale ("agree"..."don't agree") from 1..5. What is the command for creating a frequency table which looks like this (i.e. count number of occurrences of 1, 2, ...5 over all rows for each column)

```
        p1      p2     p3  ....
1        1        4     5
2        4       45     7
3       78       34     6
4        5       55     8
5        4       22    67  ....
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data:

```
df = data.frame(q1=c(F,T,T),q2=c(T,F,F),q3=rep(T,3), p1=c(1,2,1), p2=c(3,4,5), p3=c(4,4,2))
```

You can try:

```
library(qdapTools)
t(mtabulate(df[grep('q',names(df), value=T)]))

#      q1 q2 q3
#FALSE  1  2  0
#TRUE   2  1  3

t(mtabulate(df[grep('p',names(df), value=T)]))
#  p1 p2 p3
#1  2  0  0
#2  1  0  1
#3  0  1  0
#4  0  1  2
#5  0  1  0
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, also for mentioning grep(), very helpful!